# Batch file: find missing files in a folder using a list in a .txt file and output missing files to another .txt file

Tags: batch-file

1. I have a "list.txt" with a list of filename (without extention). Each line contains another file name.The txt file is located in "C:\Users***\Downloads\File Collection\list.txt"
2. I have a folder with files. The filees are located in "E:\Downloads\File Download"
3. Now I want to check which files from the "list.txt" are missing in the folder and output the missing files to another file called "missing.txt" in "C:\Users***\Downloads\File Collection\missing.txt"

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

I am a complete noob when it comes to batch files. I have tried several scrips that I found somewhere online, but none would put out a "missing.txt" in the folder I specified.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. But the question itself is not a good place for a solution. That's what answers are for (self answering is encouraged on this site). Tip: `if exist "%%i.*" ...` - the quotes make it safe against possible spaces in the filenames.